# When are arrays not passed by reference

Tags: javascript, arrays, pass-by-reference

It is my understanding that non-primitive types in JS are passed by reference not by value.

However, in the following code, when I log test.array_reference I am getting the initial value of test_array rather than a reference to the updated array that I expect

```js
function tester() {
  let test_array = [];

  function change_array() {
    test_array = ["foo"];
  }

  return {
    array_reference: test_array,
    change_array: change_array
  };
}
test = tester();
test.change_array();
console.log(test.array_reference); // why is this the initial value and not a reference to the updated array
```

What am I missing?  Are arrays not always passed by reference?

Comment: The object contains a reference to the original array. Reassigning the variable doesn't change that.

Comment: Use `test_array[0] = "foo";` to modify the array.

Comment: Nothing is passed by reference. Objects are passed by (object) sharing. Modification to an object modifies the object (truth!), independently of variables that may evaluate to the object or assignments to such. See duplicate.

Comment: I see, I did not realize that I was not modifying the original array by assigning ["foo"] to it. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction @Barmar

Comment: If you're familiar with C-like languages, think of variables, array elements, and object properties all as pointers. You're reassigning the pointer, which doesn't affect other pointers that happened to point to the same memory. It's the difference between `ptr = new_val` and `*ptr = new_val`.